# My Wordpress posts that where in Chinese are now question marks

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am running a WordPress 2.8.2 blog. A few days ago all my posts that were in Chinese characters were fine. But today i noticed all of them are broken with question marks???? I have made no changes to any files or settings, someone else could've but it is highly unlikely and no one has confessed to anything yet. The topics and categories are still in Chinese but only the content in the post themselves are broken. I found that new posts work just fine, Title and content are in Chinese, but the old posts are still broken. So I went to my wp_posts table in MYSQl and looked at post_title and post_content. Everything in post_title is in Chinese, but the data in post_content are ???? except for the new post which is in Chinese. So I'm trying to narrow down what could have happened. Was it a WP problem, something happened with my database, or something with my hosting provider? I have no mysql backup so I don't know if there is anything i can do to fix the problem. I am a little new at this and im just wondering what could have caused this problem. Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could be the wrong collation setting for the table in database.

http://leepingloon.com/?p=13

Hope it helps you.